# Cypher : Return ALL if a parameter is NULL else return specific item

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Below is the cypher query which i am using.

```
MATCH rel=(r:Report)-[:REPORT_CONTAINS_SCHEDULE]->(s:Schedule)
WHERE r.name=$rep_name AND s.name=$sch_val 
RETURN rel
```

`$rep_name, $sch_val` are parameters.

If the parameter `$sch_val` is null or empty, it should return all the rows under the node `Schedule` else if the parameter `$sch_val` contains value, it should return only the selected `Schedule` value.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more condition in `WHERE` to match only `rep_name` when `sch_val` is `null`.

```
MATCH rel=(r:Report)-[:REPORT_CONTAINS_SCHEDULE]->(s:Schedule)
WHERE (r.name=$rep_name AND $sch_val IS NULL) OR (r.name=$rep_name AND s.name=$sch_val)
RETURN rel
```

Comment: Thanks much. Looks like an easy and simple solution - didn't strike it to me :)

Comment: what happens if it is a list ? SO I have a IN query, should return all if list is empty ?